# Can you recommend an online survey platform for 5k+ participants?

Tags: survey, internet

I am planning to perform an online behavioral survey across a nationwide sample, and I expect several thousand responses.  I expect to have not that many questions (perhaps 3 pages, 8 qs each), require skip logic, and would like it to redirect back to a page of my choice.  I also need it to be hosted, as local webhosting is not an appealing option for me.  I do not need reports or fancy user interface.

Has anyone been involved in a survey of this scale, and do you have a platform you recommend?

- I am aware of [REDCap](http://project-redcap.org/) but my institution does not have access to it.
- [SurveyMonkey's Gold plan](http://www.surveymonkey.com/pricing/details?t=0) appears to meet my needs, but I would like to review alternatives
- AFAIK [Google Docs Forms](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809) doesn't have skip logic
- [LimeSurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org) was recommended in [a related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/what-tool-do-you-use-to-communicate-your-survey-questionnaires)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: We have successfully used LimeSurvey with about 4500 participants and a much longer survey (30 pages, 5-15 questions each) with branching and skipping logic. I don't know about hosting though since our installation was at our university's datacententer. Make sure you get fast loading times, bad performance can easily annoy potential participants and drive them off.

Comment: is free a requirement?

Comment: No, I'm willing to pay a reasonable fee for survey hosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survey Monkey is likely to work out well if your question formats are not too creative and if you don't mind having the monkey logo appear on each page; some people find it takes away from the professionalism of a study.

Question Pro is a little more flexible than Survey Monkey and also a little more difficult to master.

If you have complex skips and/or creative, nonstandard formats and/or you want something for the long term, I recommend Key Survey.  Colleagues of mine did a thorough search and found it to be a good program and a good value and they are happy with it after a year of use.  Unlike the other 2 I mentioned, Key has not had server problems which interrupt surveys, and they don't make unannounced changes to their platform which can surprise and confound the survey designer.